# create an array with data from setId

Tags: java, getter

I almost don`t know Java (1 week studing).

```
List<User> u = new ArrayList<User>(); 
u.add(new User(1,5));
u.add(new User(2,4));
```

In this case the data were inserted into an array from the constructor of the class. But I have to use getter and setter something like: an array with `setId(1,2,3,4)` and  `setName('John','Mike','ellen','Bart')`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Arraylist<User> u = new Arraylist<User>();

User user1 = new User(1,5);
user1.setId(1);
user1.setName('John');
u.add(user1);

User user2 = new User(2,4);
user2.setId(2);
user2.setName('Mike');
u.add(user2);
```

Comment: One man study me to make it by such a way:                   private static voidstatic User user=new User();
 static List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();  addToList(int id, int coefficient){
  user.setId(id);
  user.setCf(coefficient);
  userList.add(user); 
 }
 private static void init(){
    addToList(1,5);
       addToList(2,4);
       addToList(3,8);
       addToList(4,2);
       addToList(5,3);
       addToList(6,1);
       addToList(7,6);
       addToList(8,11);
 }

Comment: @user1353327: Yes. Looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you probably mean is you need name and id methods which take an Array or a List, and add users using the values in names[] and id[].

Assuming that the arrays you pass to names[] and id[] are always of same size, you simply need to loop through the array, and for each index i,

```
u.add(new User(id[i], names[i]);
```

Otherwise, you will need to place additional checks on the size of the arrays.

Comment: for id I agree but how to insert in loop names?

Comment: if you store names in a String array, lets take your example. If the value of i is 2, you look for the string at index 2, which is "ellen" and pass it to the user constructor along with id.